# How to verify whether it is successfully navigating to twitter login page after clicking on twitter icon from application

Tags: selenium

I need to verify after clicking on twitter icon whether it is sucessfully navigating to twitter login page.

I used xpath:
eg: `driver.findElement(By.xpath()).click`

Successfull message displaying in script but twitter login page is not displaying.

Comment: Use Assert.assertEquals(expected, original).  For more information, Kindly share your code. I'll help you. Happy Learning. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple,

//wait for page to load

```
Assert.assertEquals("Twitter",driver.getTitle().trim())
```

or

```
if(driver.getTitle().trim().equals("Twitter")){
   //good job u r inside twitter
}
```

Comment: public static void clickOnTwitterIcon() throws Exception
 {
  //To verify email option can clickable
  if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("footerTwitterButton_XPATH")))
    .isEnabled())
  {
   //Click on Twitter icon
   GUIFunctions.clickElement(driver,By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("footerTwitterButton_XPATH")), "Twitter Icon");
   Thread.sleep(10000);
  }
 }